# Convolutional Neural Net for multiple images that represent one instance

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a classification task where I am trying to identify, let's say, whether an "application" is pass/failed based on document images. Instead of classifying a single image, one application can have one or more documents. The data looks something like:

```
 Application_1          (PASS)
     - document1.jpg
     - document2.png
 Application_2          (PASS)
     - document1.jpg
 Application_3          (FAIL)
     - document1.jpg
     - document2.jpg
     - document3.jpg
     - document4.jpg
```

Each Application has a pass/fail label based on the document contents, e.g. a passport may pass by itself, a license + recommendation letter may pass, but a license by itself may not pass.

I have classifier based on the text from the documents but the image content is important. Is it possible to train a CNN where the input is an arbitrary number of images, rather than a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  One possibility is to simply concatenate the image files into one.  Another is to adapt your input layer to accept all four files.  You have to configure your CNN topology to handle the various shapes of data as the input layer provides them.

Conceptually, this is little different from writing a CNN's ingestion layer to handle a single image, but of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just processing images 1 at a time(in a batch), record their scores, and then average(or any other algorithm that works for you) them out to get a final score of the document?

This will need less/none model redesign, and next to none new training.

Comment: Because they are not independent

Comment: ok, how about you make it still one image at a time input, but change the output from Pass/Fail to, just an example, document type map and Pass/Fail prob? also make it so score from different documents affects the final score differently.